# Move files with different extensions at once

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to rewrite I .cmd batch file to a PowerShell .ps1 file. But I am failing at the `Move-Item` command and I don't know why. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Batch .cmd File (everything works correctly):

```batch
cd ../Grammar
java -jar ..\Tools\antlr-4.7-complete.jar ClarionLexer.g4 -Dlanguage=JavaScript
java -jar ..\Tools\antlr-4.7-complete.jar ClarionExprParser.g4 -visitor -no-listener -Dlanguage=JavaScript
MOVE /Y *.js ..\JavaScript\src\Generated
MOVE /Y *.tokens ..\JavaScript\src\Generated
cd ../JavaScript
```

PowerShell .ps1 Script (Does not move the files):

```bsh
Set-Location -Path ..\Grammar -PassThru
Start-Process java.exe -ArgumentList '-jar', '..\Tools\antlr-4.7-complete.jar ClarionLexer.g4 -Dlanguage=JavaScript ClarionExprParser.g4 -visitor -no-listener -Dlanguage=JavaScript'

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path ..\Grammar | Where {($_.Extension -eq '.js') -or ($_.Extension -eq '.tokens')} | Move-Item -Destination ..\JavaScript\src\Generated
Set-Location ../JavaScript -PassThru

#Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

---

UPDATE:

I have now decided to run line by line the commands:
Before I start I have in my Grammar Folder only 2 files: ClarionExprParser and ClarionLexer.

Running only this part:

```
Set-Location -Path ..\Grammar -PassThru
Start-Process java.exe -ArgumentList '-jar', '..\Tools\antlr-4.7-complete.jar ClarionLexer.g4 -Dlanguage=JavaScript ClarionExprParser.g4 -visitor -no-listener -Dlanguage=JavaScript'
```

I have now in my Grammar folder additionally the following files: ClarionExprParser.js, ClarionExprParser.tokens, ClarionExprParserVisitor.js, ClarionLexer.js, ClarionLexer.tokens
that means that the command works correctly.

Next running the second part:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path ..\Grammar | Where {($_.Extension -eq '.js') -or ($_.Extension -eq '.tokens')} | Move-Item -Destination ..\JavaScript\src\Generated -Force
Set-Location ../JavaScript -PassThru
```

works also correctly.

But when I put everything together it does not work 100% correctly. It seams as if it copies the files. The files are not moved from the folder Grammar, but they are copied to the folder Generated.

Maybe the problem is that the command Move is not waiting for Start-Process command to finish.

Here is a debug point set as suggested in the comments:
[image]

Comment: You had put the `-Destination` for `Move-Item` on the next line but now that your scripts have been edited outside of your original post, I have no idea if @Ansgar has fixed your issue. Please try it again before reposting.

Comment: For one thing, your batch script starts 2 Java processes whereas your PowerShell script starts (or tries to start) only one with all arguments combined. Did you verify that the files you want to move are generated correctly in the first place? How *exactly* are you "ailing at the `Move-Item` command"?

Comment: @compo Hmm... I expected the parser to recognize that the command continues on the next line, since only the argument was wrapped, but apparently it doesn't in this case. Reverted that fixup.

Comment: @Devid, I have re-edited your question, to hopefully have recreated the code sections as you originally posted them but without the unintentional wrapping. Until you have verified the code as it now looks on the forum, we will be unable to correct any mistakes with it.

Comment: @Devid Does that Java proccess is generating the filed you want to move ? If yes, it might be, like @Ansgar Wiechers wrote, problem that not all your files were generated. I suggest you to open ISE (powershell_ise from Run), change the Get-ChildItem to: `$result = $GetChildItem - Recurse...` (without the Move-Item pipeline) and put breakpoint after the `$result` and check what it contains. Maybe your files were not generated yet. Please update.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yes the files are generated correctly. They are generated in the folder Grammar, but afterwards they are not moved to the Generated folder.

Comment: @Compo the reedited code works. But without -Force at the end I get the message: `Cannot create a file when that file already exists.` but with -Force at the end it is also not working correctly.

Comment: @E235 I get an compiler error when I try to replace GetChildItem with $result = $GetChildItem - Recurse...

Comment: @Devid There is a space in `- Recurse`, it should be `-Recurse`.

Comment: @E235 Still I get compiler error.

Comment: Please update the question with the exact code you're running and the exact error message you're getting from that code.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers the -Force is missing, it just tells me that I can't overwrite the files otherwise. I updated the question. I think that the commands don't wait for each other to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have an asynchronic problem here.
You start the java process and before it finished you are trying to move the files.
You can solve it by waiting untill the java process to be finished.
**Small example on notepad.exe:**

```
$myProcess = Start-Process notepad.exe -PassThru

do{
    $myProcess = Get-Process -Id $myProcess.Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

}while($myProcess -ne $null)
```

**Solution for your code:**

```
Set-Location -Path ..\Grammar -PassThru
$javaProcess = Start-Process java.exe -ArgumentList '-jar', '..\Tools\antlr-4.7-complete.jar ClarionLexer.g4 -Dlanguage=JavaScript ClarionExprParser.g4 -visitor -no-listener -Dlanguage=JavaScript' -PassThru
do{
    $javaProcess = Get-Process -Id $javaProcess.Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

}while($javaProcess -ne $null)

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path ..\Grammar | Where {($_.Extension -eq '.js') -or ($_.Extension -eq '.tokens')} | Move-Item -Destination ..\JavaScript\src\Generated
Set-Location ../JavaScript -PassThru
```

Comment: Now everything works correctly. Do you know how I can make the program so that it shows me success message if everything is fine and failure message if there is a error.

Comment: You first need to decide what can go wrong. For example, maybe the `Move-Item` will fail so you can put `try{}catch{}` commands. Also,if you know what are the names of the files that the Java is creating you can make a function that after the Java finished run, it will check if all the files were created and if not will send an error and etc.